# How to refer to the scope of a controller in Angular

Tags: angularjs

All:

Right now, I defined a basic module and controller in main.js:

**main.js**

```
var app = angular.module("test", []);
app.controller("main", ["$scope", function($scope){
    $scope.data = [];
}]);
```

And I refer to that module in another sub.js:

**sub.js**

```
//From some tutorial I learned that remove the [] in module can refer to that module rather than re-defined it
var app = angular.module("test");
// Here comes my question, how to refer to that main controller?
```

I want to define something may be related to sub.js in main controller scope, I wonder how can I refer to it and add variable to its scope.

Thanks

Comment: don't redeclare `var app` in another file. Think of all the files being printed in a page like one big file. Really not clear what you are asking otherwise though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Services are used for sharing data between controllers. They are singletons and make everything much easier than complicating the inter-controller communication some other way.

And you shouldn't define controllers twice (not only a bad practice, but it won't work).

So, use the service to save what you need from the main controller, and then access it from the sub.

---

UPDATE

See this simple example I made, the Sub controller is accessing values set from the Main controller:

```js
angular.module('app', [])
.controller('Main', function(myService){
  myService.setData('some data from Main ctrl');
})
.controller('Sub', function(myService, $scope){
  $scope.data = myService.getData();
})
.service('myService', function(){
  var data;
  return {
    setData: function(d){
      data = d;
    },
    getData: function(){
      return data;
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<body ng-app="app">
  <div ng-controller="Main"></div>
  <div ng-controller="Sub">
    {{data}}
  </div>

  </body>
```

Comment: So I can refer to a service in a different js file as long as I declare the module it belong to?

Comment: You can inject services in controllers, so if that's what you meant by refering to them, then yes.

Comment: Thanks, if I seperate the code into several .js file, I still confused how can I refer to that controller to inject my service(I just want to work in same controller)?

Comment: You're welcome. As I said, you don't use the same controller across multiple files, but set the data from one controller, and get the data into the controller you're using in the other file.

Comment: Ok, now I C. So if I separate code, I should focus on put diff jobs in diff service, and put them together in a same controller scope or among controllers?

Comment: A good practice is to have a separate file for each controller. So yeah, different jobs in different services used across multiple controllers within the same module.

Comment: One last thing is: how do you know the getData will be called AFTER  setData called? Is it following the definition order of controllers?

Comment: Actually, it's the order they appear in the DOM... Still, if you're unsure what will happen at which time, you can emit/broadcast changes so that all the controllers that rely on the data can act accordingly.